# How to configure stereo outputs of a soundcard as two separate outputs and send audio to each from different audio inputs?

Tags: audio, naudio, channel

I am trying to send audio data to the right and left output channels of a soundcard's output port separately. The right and left channels should get data from two different audio sources.. Is it possible with NAudio?

Answer (score 0):

WaveChannel32 has pan as parameter. Specify 1 or -1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, read my article on [handling multi-channel audio in NAudio](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/handling-multi-channel-audio-in-naudio.html). The `MultiplexingSampleProvider` enables you to route different inputs to different soundcard outputs.